# How does this site load new page and URL with no white refresh?

Tags: html, ajax

http://www.espnfc.com/team/nigeria/657/index
Select team/group from category and select Brazil

If you notice, the url changes (no hash tags), then there is a CSS progress bar loader at top and page loads quickly (without white document refresh)

Is this site using some framework?

Comment: Look into the [HTML5's History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Answer (score 2):

**AJAX call** to refresh a portion of the page + **history.pushState** to change the URL and save state... It's all been out there for a while.

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Every framework works on its language (like jQuery is JavaScript, for example), so there's absolutely nothing a framework can do that the original language can't.